# Managing ObjectContext in Workflow Foundation 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working with Workflow Foundation 4 and Entity Framework 4.1.

I am building my workflow with sets of ReceiveAndSendReply activities. It makes sense to me to use a single ObjectContext (or DbContext, now) per set of receive and send reply activities.

How should I manage the ObjectContext? Are there activities just for this or do I need to manually manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better not to use a DbContext or an ObjectContect directely in your worklfow. Put these in a workflow extension and let those load POCO entoties for you. Make sure you only use POCO entities in your worklfow and that they are marked as serializable. Doing it another way will certainly cause problems with workflow persistence and long running workflows. And even if you don't need persistence now it is better to do it the right way for any future development.

Comment: Why not use DbContext in the workflow? I understand that I can't expect to use a DbContext that has been deserialized from persistence. I've never worked with POCO entities before and I could really use NOT to learn a whole new microsoft thing on top of having to learn WF4.

Comment: Everything that is part of the workflow state needs to be serializable and I am pretty sure the DbContext isn't. Using POCO's isn't hard, you can even use the standard designer and use the POCO generation template.

Comment: I think Maurice doesn't mean "don't use EF in workflows, period." I think he means, "Don't reference them in your XAML." (E.g., as a workflow variable.) Using EF inside a CodeActivity, e.g., should be fine.

Comment: I believe that since I am using the new DbContext, my entities are already POCO's. So, I'm still fuzzy on how to expose a dbContext object to my code activities. You're saying to use an extension, and not to create a workflow variable for the dbcontext, because it cannot be persisted. But I know that my DbContext needs to live as long as the activities between recieve and sendreply activities, so that activities can share it. How do I control this using an extension?

Comment: You can create an extension and share that between different activities. The context will let you retrieve it.

Comment: Yes, but how do I control which instance of DbContext the extension gives me? The DbContext instance I am expecting to get needs to be controlled from the CodeActivities requesting it.

Comment: The extensions doen't give you a DbContext. The extension is a repository that returns or saves entities for you.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to abstract away the DbContext. I want to use it. Is there anything wrong with just storing a DbContext to HttpContext.Current.Items and retrieving that when I need it in the CodeActivity?

Comment: Yes, you are missing the point of workflow execution. The workflow doesn't just execute as part of a request, it can keep on executing independently. Besides even during an WCF operation there is no HttpContext.Current or OperationContext.Current to store items. And hiding the DbContext is not a bad thing but the exactly opposite. Its a good thing and not just for long running, also for unit testing your activities.

Comment: Ok. I'll create this extension to take care of my data access. But, I still need to use the dbcontext in the extension. Somewhere, I'll have to manage the lifetime of the DbContext. I may want it to live longer than just for the duration of a single activity. Shouldn't the activities between Receive and SendReply be considered atomic and I wouldn't want a new DbContext for each activity? How can I accomplish that? You obviously know exactly what to do and I am struggling here, so if you could do more than a comment I would seriously appreciate it.

Comment: There are various ways of doing that. For example you can model it sort of like a TransactionScope activity where all child activities can use the same DbContext. In general though it is best to create a DbContext, load some data and then dispose it and recreate one for the next action.

Comment: If you say waste the dbcontext, that's fine with me and that's what I'll do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no built-in activities for this.

We do it with a custom service behavior and `GetExtension`, like in [this post](http://www.cauldwell.net/patrick/blog/UnityAndWorkflowServicesHostedInIIS.aspx).

Beware, though: If your workflow has a persistence point, implicit or explicit, you cannot expect the Context to survive this!