# Entity Framework 4.1 - How to make DbContext entities serializable

Tags: .net, entity-framework, workflow-foundation, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using the EF4.1 DbContext code generation, which creates POCO entities like this:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public System.Guid EmployeeGUID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LatestHireDate { get; set; }
    public string CompanyEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> SupervisorGUID { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorFullName { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorCompanyEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string JobCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Do you *really* need the whole entity for WF 4, knowing full well that the context will never be serializable and hence the entity will be disconnected? I question the design, here.

Comment: Deleting one sentence from the question does not clarify why this design is a good idea.

Comment: Are you asking how to serialize `Employee`? Why do you need to serialize it? I don't think that is a good idea...

Comment: I didn't realize that I was obligated to explain my design to you. I thought this was a place to get answers to technical questions. But since you are so interested in my design, I would appreciate some help from you. Very broadly: ASP.NET web site housing workflows, authentication/authorization, and the XAP files for the silverlight client. That same silverlight client, as part of the workflow, needs to get the very same employee entity above and show ALL of it's data to the end user. If it's such a bad idea to include the entity in the workflow, how can I ever send it back to the client?

Comment: By the way, Maurice is the one that told me to use serializable POCO entities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097786/managing-objectcontext-in-workflow-foundation-4/6099679#6099679 I thought that since every one regards him as a WF4 Genius that I should do it.

Comment: You are never obligated to explain anything. But you are asking for help, so it would *benefit you personally* if you chose to ask a complete question.

Comment: @Craig - I'm asking for your guidance in my comment above, where I explain the structure of the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of serializing your DBContext entities, I would create DTOs (Data Transfer Object) that represents what really needs to be serialized. Then, I would use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map your DBContext entities to your DTOs.

Update: [This is a bit out of date](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=155), but the author explains some of the great uses for AutoMapper.

Comment: The fact that automapper exists and I didn't know about it makes me sad.  Thanks for the info.